# Error while opening Forge source in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project, minecraft-forge

It is shown to me this error when I try to open Minecraft project. I've used forge source 1.7.2 version 1024.
I've run in `cmd.exe` the commands:

1. `gradlew.bat setupDecomWorkspace --refresh-dependencies`
2. `gradlew.bat eclipse`

[image: Print Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you typed `gradlew.bat setupDecomWorkspace --refresh-dependencies` when you should by typing `gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies`. Notice the 'p' in Decomp.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `gradlew.bat setupDevWorkspace eclipse` ?

As shown in the forge installation video (for windows) from one of the developers (found in the readme):
[LexManos' Install Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VEdtQLuLO0&feature=youtu.be)